# Add provably fair systeme

Tags: php, hash

I work for a slots game, and I need to add provable fairness for the results.

Array for slots

```
    $initial = array(
    array('1','2','3','4'),
    array('1','2','3','4'),
    array('1','2','3','4')
    );

    if($start) ...
```

Thank you

Comment: What you're asking isn't entirely clear.  You say you need someone to verify/complete the code.  Is it missing something?  Are you able to test it to see if it works?  Most code can be verified by executing it.  Perhaps you want to know if it is secure?

Comment: Thank for reply yes code is work but i need for view if function fisher yate is correct or not and if all function is secure (because i use client seed with javascript not php)

Comment: Alright, I proposed an edit to your question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Ah thank for this and sorry i dont speak very good english ^^